# Threads in c++, cannot use parameters

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, compiler-errors, g++

I am trying to start a thread t:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

void function(int p1, int p2, int p3){
  std::cout<<p1<<p2<<p3<<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  std::cout<<"starting"<<std::endl;
  std::thread t(function, 1, 2, 3);
  std::cout<<"created thread"<<std::endl;
  t.join();
  std::cout<<"end"<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

My compiler tells me this:

```
doesntwork.cpp:12:15: error: no matching constructor for
      initialization of 'std::thread'
  std::thread t(function, 1, 2, 3);
              ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:408:9: note: 
      candidate constructor template not viable: requires single
      argument '__f', but 4 arguments were provided
thread::thread(_Fp __f)
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:289:5: note: 
      candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 4
      were provided
    thread(const thread&);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:296:5: note: 
      candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but
      4 were provided
    thread() _NOEXCEPT : __t_(_LIBCPP_NULL_THREAD) {}
    ^
1 error generated.
```

In the first case it tells me that for the thread t, there is no constructor that can use more than 1 parameter, while if I just remove the arguments (p1, p2, p3) it doesn't work either because I am not passing any argmuent....

Compiler information:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr 

--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

built command used: `g++ doesntwork.cpp -o doesntwork.out`

Is there something different you have to do when compiling with threads? Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: #import - that is not c++, please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: yeah sorry meant #include

Comment: I'm going to assume you actually declared your function properly, but [this seems to work otherwise](https://ideone.com/iwPm5i)

Comment: `void function(p1, p2, p3)` -- This is not C++.  Actually post a [mcve].  If you get a compiler error, post the *exact* code that gives the error, not your recollection of the code or fake C++ code.

Comment: right I made a program that should work and updated the question sorry again, it still does not compile.

Comment: The initialization of `t` is correct, the initialization of `t2` is an error. If you take out `t2` and fix typoes in the rest of the code then it [should compile successfully](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NRTiyY). If you are still having trouble please copy and paste the EXACT code that is giving trouble  , also give your compiler version and the build command you are using

Comment: The error message suggests you are using clang++ and not g++  (I heard some macos systems come with "g++" aliased to clang)

Comment: You missed a semicolon on your `t.join()` call.

Comment: use `-std=c++11` compile switch

Comment: adding -std=c++11 worked! Thanks @M.M I had no idea that was a thing that could go wrong...

Comment: ok, I voted to reopen, once it is open someone will post that as an answer

Comment: It will remain an eternal mystery why compilers don't default to latest version mode. I think clang started doing that since version 6 so maybe something is fishy with your compiler installation (it seems to mention library version 4.2.1 which is quite old)

Comment: Yeah it doesn't seem to make sence.... Thanks for being patient with me as well! And sorry to everyone for not being super clear from the beginning.

Comment: @Jacques-APortal -- Once the code was provided and compiler mentioned, I don't think this should be downvoted, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On macOS, g++ (from Xcode: Version 10.0 (10A255)) is aliased to clang which by default does not work with c++11 threads. To solve the problem you have to use the `-std=c++11` switch.

Example:

```
g++ -std=c++11 fileToCompile.cpp -o outputFile.out
```

This should let you compile c++ code using c++11 threads.

Thank you to @M.M for providing the answer above in the comments.